# Sonar dead store to local variable

Tags: java, sonarqube

I have the following code and sonar is telling me the following error message:

```
Dead store to descriptions1 in new com.dscsag.dsct2c.test.TestStep(Integer, String, Model)
```

In the follwing code:

```
for (Integer count = 0; count < testStepCount; count++)
    {
      if (xmlReader.isTestExistingForOrderNumber(count, orderNumber, version))
      {
        if (xmlReader.checkForDuplicateTest(orderNumber, count, version))
        {
          GlobalVariables.LOGGING_logger.error("### " + this.getClass().getSimpleName()
              + ": There are one or more duplicated order numbers for test " + count + " under test step " + orderNumber + ".");
          model.setStatusText("STATUS_DUPLICATED_TEST", orderNumber.toString(), StatusCode.ERROR);
          throw new Exception();
        }
        else
        {
          GlobalVariables.LOGGING_logger.info("### " + this.getClass().getSimpleName() + ": No duplicated found for test " + count
              + " under test step " + orderNumber + ".");
          boolean functionNeeded = xmlReader.isFunctionNeededForOrderNumber(orderNumber, count, version);

          String[][] descriptions1 = new String[2][descriptions[0].length];

          for (int a = 0; a < this.descriptions[0].length; a++)
          {
            descriptions1[0][a] = descriptions[0][a];
            descriptions1[1][a] = xmlReader.getTestDescription(descriptions[0][a], orderNumber, count, version);
          }

          ArrayList<String> filesString = xmlReader.getTestFilesForOrderNumber(orderNumber, count, version);
          ArrayList<File> filesFile = new ArrayList<File>();
          Iterator<String> it = filesString.iterator();
          while (it.hasNext())
          {
            File file = new File(GlobalVariables.PATH_TestFiles
                + xmlReader.getValueDocumentConfiguration(XmlElements.CAD_APPL, XmlElements.TESTING_ENVIRONMENT, null) + "/" + it.next());
            filesFile.add(file);

            GlobalVariables.LOGGING_logger.info("### " + this.getClass().getSimpleName() + ": Added file to test " + count
                + " under test step " + orderNumber + ": \"" + file.getName() + "\"");
          }

          testObjectsList.add(new TestObject(functionNeeded, xmlReader.getFunctionNameForOrderNumber(orderNumber, count, version),
              descriptions1, filesFile));

          GlobalVariables.LOGGING_logger.info("### " + this.getClass().getSimpleName() + ": Finally created test object for test " + count
              + " under test step " + orderNumber + ".");
        }
      }
      else
      {
        model.setStatusText("STATUS_NO_TEST", count.toString(), StatusCode.WARNING);
      }
    }
  }
```

Can you see why I store to "dead" `descriptions1`? I think I have to use this variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its a false positive of sonar. Sonar works on the compiled code, not your source. I guess the access to `descriptions1` is optimized away or replaced by the compiler, thus sonar cant see it.

Comment: You can add the file to the exclusion filter. Maybe you can also disable the "dead store to local variable" pattern for this file, but i don't know if its possible.